# Destroy http-only cookie with cookie-parser

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, httponly

I am using [cookie-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-parser) to create a http-only cookie that holds the token for a logged-in user.

Then I need to either destroy that cookie or make it expire, when the user hits "logout".

How can I destroy (or at least edit) the cookie?

Will the following do the trick ?

`res.cookie("SESSIONID", null, {httpOnly:true, secure:true});`

Thank you

Comment: Are you using passport?

Comment: @JimBaldwin Nope, nowhere in the project

Comment: It should be easy enough to try it and see what happens...